# How do I get raw text with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

I have a xml like this:

```
<link>
www.link1.com
</link>
<link>
www.link2.com
</link>
```

I have tried this code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup 
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(results2)     #Beautiful Soup
linklist = soup.findAll('link')
print soup
```

Using this code, the output is

```
[<link>www.link1.com</link>,<link>www.link2.com</link>]
```

But I want an output like this

```
[www.link1.com, www.link2.com]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
linklist = [el.string for el in soup.findAll('link')]
```

Comment: wow thank you very much! it works but the output is like [u'www.link1.com', u'www.link2.com].. how do i get the unicode thingy off?

Comment: Yup, you get a list containing strings of the URL for the link - is that not what you want?

Comment: it is what i want, thank you but i want only the www.link1.com. the output is u'www.link.com. can i get the u and 's out?

Comment: The `u'www.link1.com'` just indicates it's unicode. Just `print linklist[0]` to see or alternatively, if you only want the first `<link>` use `soup.find` instead of `soup.findAll`

Comment: oh but i am going to put this list values as url in another code. So u'www.link1.com' doesn't work... i understand it's a unicode but i need to get rid of these u and 's. thank you for your advice it really helped me a lot:D

Comment: @user1512491 just don't worry about the u and `''`s - They're **not** part of the actual string... it's just the way it's displayed to let you **know** it's a string.

Comment: oh! thank you very much! i didn't know that. i'm kind of new in programming.. thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
links = soup.find_all('link')
link_strings = [s.string for s in links.string]
```

Comment: Do you mean `[s.string for s in links]`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """<html><link>
www.link1.com
</link>
<link>
www.link2.com
</link></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,features="xml")
linklist = soup.find_all('link')
linklist = map(lambda x: x.string, linklist)
```

note that I've changed the constructor to `BeautifulSoup` with `features="xml"` instead of `BeautifulStoneSoup` as the latter is deprecated.